# Distance of a finite dimensional subspace of a Hilbert space from a point

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, orthogonality

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $Y$ be a finite dimensional subspace of $H$. Let $x$ be an element of $H$ Then can we say that
$$
\begin{align}\text{dist}(x,Y)=\|z\|,~~~\text{ where } x=y+z~\text{ for } y\in Y,~z\in Y^{\perp}?~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)
\end{align}
$$
I am not able to prove this. While taking examples of Euclidean space $($basically $~\mathbb{R}^2)$ I found that the above statement holds, but can't prove this.
Now from definition we know that,
$$\text{dist}(x,Y)=\inf \{\|x-\alpha\|~:~ \forall \alpha \in Y\}.$$
Again since $Y$ is finite dimensional, then $Y$ is closed in $H$ and therefore there exists unique $\alpha \in Y$ such that $\text{dist}(x,Y)=\|x-\alpha\|$. But not able to prove $(1)$.
Plese help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly stated, since $Y$ is finite dimensional then $Y$ is closed in $H$.

I will carry on $z$ as $z = x-y$ where $x-y \in Y^\bot$, because it's important for the calculations that follow.

Let an element $h \in Y$. Then, it is:
\begin{align*}
\left\|x-h\right\|^2 &= \left\| x-y + y - h\right\|^2 \\ &= \left\|x-y \right\|^2 + \left\|y-h\right\|^2 \\ &\geq \left\|x-y\right\|^2. 
\end{align*}

So, that means that $\left\|x-h\right\| \geq \left\| x-y\right\|,  \forall y \in Y$. This straight-forwardly gives us that $\left\|x-y\right\| = d\left(x,Y\right)$.